# R: improving speed for t-test for each row in a data frame

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, t-test

I am trying to improve the speed of a t-test loop for a data-frame.

I have a large data frame (~15000 rows and 205 columns). Each column is a cell and each row is a gene. I can group the columns into 2 groups based on their identity provided in a different reference table.

Here is the loop I have written:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(EC)){
  ttest_result[i,2] <- rowMeans(EC)[i]
  ttest_result[i,3] <- rowMeans(CP)[i]
  ttest_result[i,4] <- (ttest_result[i,2] - ttest_result[i,3])
  ttest_result[i,5] <- (ttest_result[i,2] / ttest_result[i,3])
  ttest_result[i,6]<- t.test(EC[i,],CP[i,], var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
  pb$tick()
}
```

This loop requires me to split the original data frame into 2 data frames based on the column identities. However, this loop takes over 45 mins to complete.

I am wondering if you all have suggestion on what I can do differently? How do I potentially use apply functions to improve the speed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If all of the columns are numerical, convert it to a matrix. row operations on a data.frame are incredibly slow. You'd do even a bit better if you transpose the matrix and operate on the columns rather than on the rows.

Answer (score 2):

limma is the solution.

```
> #library(BiocInstaller)
> #biocLite("limma")
> 
> #create a dataset
> library(limma)
> data <- matrix(rnorm(15000*205),15000,205)
> dim(data)
[1] 15000   205
> rownames(data) <- paste("Gene",1:15000)
> str(data)
 num [1:15000, 1:205] -0.55603 -0.45478 -1.76432 0.05198 0.00844 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:15000] "Gene 1" "Gene 2" "Gene 3" "Gene 4" ...
  ..$ : NULL
> # save the grouping in a factor
> f<-sample(c("ctrl","treat"),size = 205,replace = T)
> 
> # perform the comparison gene per grouping
> t<-Sys.time()
> design <- model.matrix(~0+f)
> colnames(design) <- c("ctrl","treat")
> fit2 <- lmFit(data,design)
> contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts("treat-ctrl", levels=design)
> fit2 <- contrasts.fit(fit2, contrast.matrix)
> fit2 <- eBayes(fit2)
> top_table<-topTable(fit2, adjust="BH",coef=1,number =15000)
> dim(top_table)
[1] 15000     6
> head(top_table)
                logFC     AveExpr         t      P.Value adj.P.Val          B
Gene 12434 -0.6238005  0.07603032 -4.454575 8.459040e-06 0.1268856 -0.5006572
Gene 11609 -0.5827713  0.11178709 -4.156804 3.242956e-05 0.2174629 -1.0670677
Gene 5924   0.5729590 -0.02980352  4.089151 4.349258e-05 0.2174629 -1.1903102
Gene 10460 -0.5274251 -0.07930193 -3.770822 1.632559e-04 0.5747294 -1.7431451
Gene 5950   0.5216678 -0.03304759  3.730682 1.915765e-04 0.5747294 -1.8096840
Gene 14518  0.5053476 -0.05750282  3.612195 3.044821e-04 0.6298752 -2.0019558
> Sys.time()-t
Time difference of 0.3026412 secs
```

notice that it also print the adjusted p-value (you can choose the method), which is one of the criteria to filter genes of interest.

Comment: you are computational biology person it seems

Answer (score 1):

```
nc <- 205
nr <- 15000

set.seed(30)
EC <- matrix(rnorm(nr * nc), nr, nc)
CP <- matrix(rnorm(nr * nc), nr, nc)
```

Calculate row means and vars before loop (this was your biggest mistake, to put this operation into loop):

```
meansEC <- rowMeans(EC)
meansCP <- rowMeans(CP)

require(matrixStats)
varsEC <- rowVars(EC)
varsCP <- rowVars(CP)
```

Using pre-calculated row means and row vars we can calculate p.value much faster without t.test function (you can look at `t.test` code to extract the parts you need):

```
t.test.p.value <- function(i, j, nx, ny){
  mu <- 0
  mx <- meansEC[i]
  vx <- varsEC[i]
  my <- meansCP[j]
  vy <- varsCP[j]
  df <- nx + ny - 2
  v <- 0
  if (nx > 1) v <- v + (nx - 1)*vx
  if (ny > 1) v <- v + (ny - 1)*vy
  v <- v/df
  stderr <- sqrt(v*(1/nx + 1/ny))
  tstat <- (mx - my - mu)/stderr
  pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
  pval
}

# create resulting matrix
ttest_result <- matrix(NA, nrow(EC), 7)
t <- Sys.time()

nx <- ncol(EC)
ny <- ncol(CP)
```

Lets calculate with bout t.test.p.value function and default `t.test`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(EC)) {
  ttest_result[i, 2] <- meansEC[i]
  ttest_result[i, 3] <- meansCP[i]
  ttest_result[i, 4] <- (meansEC[i] - meansCP[i])
  ttest_result[i, 5] <- (meansEC[i] / meansCP[i])
  ttest_result[i, 6] <- t.test(EC[i, ], CP[i, ], var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
  ttest_result[i, 7] <- t.test.p.value(i, i, nx, ny)
}
t <- Sys.time() - t
t

ttest_result[1:5, 5:7]
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -0.3248217 0.35084307 0.35084307
# [2,] -2.3455622 0.11621785 0.11621785
# [3,] -2.1586716 0.01294876 0.01294876
# [4,]  1.1556035 0.98065576 0.98065576
# [5,]  1.9875296 0.92340948 0.92340948
all.equal(ttest_result[,6], ttest_result[, 7])
# [1] TRUE
```

We see that results are equal

Timing for this data using only my approach:

```
t <- Sys.time()
meansEC <- rowMeans(EC)
meansCP <- rowMeans(CP)
require(matrixStats)
varsEC <- rowVars(EC)
varsCP <- rowVars(CP)
ttest_result <- matrix(NA, nrow(EC), 7)
for (i in 1:nrow(EC)) {
  ttest_result[i, 2] <- meansEC[i]
  ttest_result[i, 3] <- meansCP[i]
  ttest_result[i, 4] <- (meansEC[i] - meansCP[i])
  ttest_result[i, 5] <- (meansEC[i] / meansCP[i])
  ttest_result[i, 6] <- t.test.p.value(i, i, nx, ny)
}
t <- Sys.time() - t
t #Time difference of 0.145169 secs
```